# SRP and a lot of classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle

I'm refactoring some code I wrote a few months ago and now I find myself creating a lot of smallish classes (few properties, 2-4 methods, 1-2 events).

Is this how it's supposed to be?  Or is this also a bit of a code smell?

I mean if a class does need a lot of methods to carry out it's responsibility, I guess that's how it's gotta be, but I'm not so sure that a lot small classes is particularly good practice either?

Answer (score 4):

Lots of small classes sounds just fine :)

Particularly if you let each class implement an interface and have the different collaborators communicate through those interfaces instead of directly with each other, you should be able to achieve a so-called **Supple Design** (a term from [Domain-Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)) with lots of loose coupling.

If you can boil it down so that important operations have the same type of output as input, you will achieve what Evans call **Closure of Operations**, which I've found to be a particularly strong design technique.

What tend to happen when you apply the SRP is that although all classes start out small, you constantly refactor, and from time to time it happens that a rush of insight clarifies that a few particular classes could be a lot richer than previously assumed.

Do it, but keep refactoring forever :)

Answer (score 3):

Lots of small classes with focused responsibilties are what srp is all about. So, yes, this is the way things are "supposed to be" as far as srp advocates are concerned. But you're seeing an explosion of the number of classes in your system and it's beginning to become very difficult to remember or to intuitively know where things are actually done, isn't it? You are, indeed, exposing a new code smell, which is the (usually unnecessary) increase of complexity that comes aong with srp. I wrote an entry about it [here](http://razingtheivorytower.blogspot.com). See if you might agree.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to find the middle way. Too many classes are sometimes overkill. From my side I try to separate concerns on a smaller level and if things are getting then refactor out more coarse grained:

> First write separate concerns by extracting methods. If you can see a group of methods  on data (instance + static fields) to form a dedicated responsibility 'extract class'.  After a while if you can see different groupings of classes inside a package do 'extract packages'.

I found this (explosion) approach more natural as creating lots of classes and packages from start on. But this also depends...: If I can already see bigger components at the beginning I already create dedicated package structures.

Maybe some more details about your code to offer some more concrete help :)